# Calling Google Ajax Search API via JQuery JSONP

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I know this has been asked a zillion times, but I still can't get my code to work.  I am trying to a simple JSONP call from my Javascript application.  The cod fragment looks like:

```
url="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=AAA&callback=?";
```

and then either:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    alert('hello 1');
  });
```

or:

```
$.ajax({url: url,
    datatype: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) { alert("hello 2"); },
    error: function(j, t, e) {  alert(t);}
});
```

Neither approach works.  The second approach results in the alert of "error".  The first does not return success either.  What am I doing wrong?  Many, many thanks!!

UPDATE: I think I found at least one problem.  Let me look more into this.

UPDATE 2: Sorry, this code actually works, at least the first approach.  There was a subtle error around this code fragment that resulted in the code not working, but overall this works just fine.  Asynchronous calls are sometimes a little tricky :-)

Answer (score 5):

Check this out  [JsFIddleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/viyancs/qThnX/3/)

```
    /*
     * create callbak function for jsonP
     * @params
     * data is response from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=AAA&callback=myjsonpfunction
     */
      function myjsonpfunction(data){
           alert(data.responseData.results) //showing results data
           $.each(data.responseData.results,function(i,rows){
              alert(rows.url); //showing  results url
           });
      }

    //request data using jsonP
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url:'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=AAA&callback=myjsonpfunction',
        type:"GET",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'myjsonpfunction',
        async:'true',
        success:function (data) {
            //alert("success");
          }
        });
      });
```

you need write a callback parameter and callback function,the google ajax apis will be return only json if you don't set of callback.

if you set url like this

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=AAA&callback=?(another)
```

the response is

`{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "bad or missing callback or context", "responseStatus": 400}`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the method you are using is deprecated: https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/reference

And has moved on to: http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

Comment: Yes, but "depricated" does not mean "not working".  If I call the URL directly, I get results.

Comment: @MarkT True, but it will stop one day. And, with `callback=?` I get an error. If `callback=?` is removed or is given a value like `callback=foo`, it works. If you are attaching a value to that `callback` it should be included in the question.

Comment: This is not how JSONP with JQuery works.  JQuery replaces callback=? with callback=<smth.>

Comment: @MarkT It doesn't appear to be responding as `JSONP`. Looks like straight `JSON`. If that is the case, you are running into a same origin policy violation.