# How to translate this PHP code into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

Using, **PHP** I have been successful in extract an IMDB id from google search.

```
$str = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/search?q=momento");
preg_match("/tt\d{7}?/", $str, $matcheid);
$id = $matcheid[0];
```

I have been unsuccessful in translating this into **Javascript**.This was my effort. Doesn't seem to work

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("GET", "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + a + "imdb", false);
http.send(null);
var googleData = http.responseText;
var id = googleData.match(/tt\d{7}?/)[0];
```

Can someone correct the code?!

Thanking you,
John

Comment: Google "same origin policy", you _need_ PHP here.

Comment: Or, you can use Google's API, but that returns different results - http://stackoverflow.com/q/9746181/1348195

Comment: I was going to reflexively downvote this question as this usually is a "write my code for me" kind of question based on the title. But then I saw you actually tried to do it yourself. So I had to upvote for being happily wrong.

Comment: *"Can someone correct the code"* No, it can't be corrected. There's nothing wrong with it other than google (and your browser) won't let you do that.

Comment: Look at your JavaScript console. Read the error messages. Use a search engine to figure out what they mean.

Comment: Thank you all! I shall try the link :0

Answer (score -1):

try converting it into JSON Array so that you can use it in both Javascript as well as in PHP